# I can't install Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

when I try to install I get this error:

```bash
pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

If I try using pip install tensorflow-gpu:

```bash
"ckaging\requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
          raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
      setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

My python version is 3.12.2 and I already try in a virtual env.
Can someone help?

Comment: Try updating your pip `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Already done, issue persist

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade to `python 3.11` or install `python 3.11` separately.

Currently Tensorflow is supported till `python 3.11` as of 15th Feb 2024

[image]

Link: **https://www.tensorflow.org/install**